# The conversion of the nvarchar value overflowed an int column VB.Net

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I am writing an application to work with my DB (on Microsoft SQL Server 2014). I have this code:

```
Private Sub Ucitaj()
    Try
        Dim command As New SqlCommand
        command.Connection = Me.conn
        command.CommandText = "select * from zaposleni where jmbg=" & Me.jmbg
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader

        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        reader.Read()

        Me.TextBox2.Text = reader("ime")
        Me.TextBox3.Text = reader("prezime")
        Me.TextBox4.Text = reader("br_rac")
        Me.TextBox5.Text = reader("tel")
        Me.TextBox6.Text = reader("datum_zap")

        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

At line: reader.Read(), it throws the following error:
{"The conversion of the nvarchar value '1008994254963' overflowed an int column."}

By the way, '1008995254963' is the value in column 'jmbg' of my first entry in the table. So I suppose, when it does comparison, it tries to convert this into int. However, my datatype in database is nvarchar(20), so why does this happen? Shouldn't it treat it as a string? Why does it try to convert it to int, when I can basically write words(not only digits) in this column and when the datatype is not an int? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue there is that you are using a literal value in your SQL code and not wrapping it in single quotes.  Literal text MUST be wrapped in single quotes so your value is interpreted as a number rather than text.  That means that, in order to compare, the value in the column is also converted to a number and it is too big for an `int`, hence the overflow.

That may make it sound like the solution is to add some single quotes but that is a dirty solution.  The proper solution is to ALWAYS use parameters to insert values into SQL code.  Doing so means that issues like this and many others  don't arise.

```
command.CommandText = "select * from zaposleni where jmbg = @jmbg"
command.Parameters.Add("@jmbg", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = Me.jmbg
```